# Python - Lookup a matching string in two large text files

Tags: python, linux, awk, lookup, large-files

I'm trying to search for values in `FILE1` within 2nd column of `FILE2`, and print the value from 3rd column of `FILE2` when matching. Below is an example of my files and output:

```
 FILE1:
1
2
3
4


FILE2:
0,1,Y,8
4,5,6,7
7,4,X,9

 OUTPUT:
Y
X
```

Can any one help me to do this?

Comment: Ok and where it didn't work when you tried it?

Comment: Hi arainone, I'm new to python, and I figure out that I should use it; since my files are around 3M lines. Unfortunately, I couldn't use any of the scripting am familiar with due to the size issue!

Comment: Take a look here, maybe you'll find a good way to handle your large file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548193/python-large-files-how-to-find-specific-lines-with-a-particular-string

Answer (score 1):

If you can fit the first file in memory, then I'd go with something like this using awk:

```
awk -F, 'NR == FNR { a[$1]; next } $2 in a { print $3 }' file1 file2
```

This stores the first field from the first file in the array `a`, then prints the third field from the second file whenever the corresponding second field matches.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Actually I've considered awk as an option, however, 1st file is around 100MB, and 2nd is 300MB. I do not think it's possible!

Comment: Sounds like you need about 100MB of RAM in that case, which isn't an unreasonable amount.

Comment: Correct, but I got a zero bytes output file. Btw, I'm using a linux in a VM, however, RAM assigned is 2GB !

Comment: If there was no output, that would suggest that the code isn't working, possibly due to a bug or a difference between your example and the real input.

Comment: I'm applying the same code with a sample of my file, and it's working fine!
getting mad :\

Comment: You need to identify the difference between the fields that are working and those that are not. For example, are there spaces between some of the fields in your input?

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution with `join`, files need to be sorted on the joined field.

```
$ join -t, -1 1 -2 2 file1 <(sort -t, -k2n file2) | cut -d, -f3
Y
X
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a variant of Tom Fenech's excellent answer (excellent in part because no sort is required), but with the advantage that the test 'NR==FNR' is not needed. It might therefore be detectably faster:

```
awk -F, -v dict=FILE1 'BEGIN {while(getline<dict){a[$1]=1}}
 $2 in a {print $3}'
```

Of course this also requires enough memory to store a hash table for FILE1, but as already pointed out, that shouldn't be a problem if FILE1 is only 100MB.